# jquery page URL load on select strange behavior

Tags: php, jquery, select

I have a select box on a page that, when you choose a value it will automatically go to that page using the id parameter set in the URL string. The form works well, until I try to add to it the code that brings in and matches the URL parameter to automatically be selected. Now, when you choose a new value, it redirects to --selected-- instead of the page URL with the new value.

If I manually load the page, i.e. vbijjaar.php?id=2017, the page loads just fine, the select menu displays 2017. But now, when I choose, 2018 or 2016 or other in the menu, as I've indicated above, it just goes to --select-- instead of vbijjaar.php?id=xxx

I'm not seeing any errors, either.

```
<form >
<select class="js-example-basic-single js-states form-control" name="jaar" id="urlSelect" onchange="window.location = jQuery('#urlSelect option:selected').val();">

       <?php
       ini_set('display_errors',1);
        error_reporting(E_ALL);

        $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'xxx', 'xxxx', 'xxx');
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT YEAR(vertrekdatum2) AS year FROM tbl_vluchtgegevens GROUP BY YEAR(vertrekdatum2) ORDER BY YEAR(vertrekdatum2) DESC ");

            while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                            {   
                $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['id']); 
                $j = $row2['year'];
       ?>
    <option value="vbijjaar.php?id=<?php echo $j ?>" <?php echo ($j == $id) ? 'selected' : '' ?>> <?php echo $j; ?> </option>
        <?php                        
            }mysqli_close($conn);
        ?>
    </select>  
<script>
    $(function(){
      // bind change event to select
      $('#urlSelect').bind('change', function () {
          var url = $(this).val(); // get selected value
          if (url) { // require a URL
              window.location = url; // redirect
          }
          return false;
      });
    });
</script>
<br />

</form>
```

Generated HTML code:

```
<form class="px-4 py-3">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="statsbyyear">Stats by Year</label>

              <select class="js-example-basic-single js-states form-control form-control-sm" width="100px" name="jaar" id="urlSelect" onchange="window.location = jQuery('#urlSelect option:selected').val();">

<option>--Select--</option>
<option value='http://globe-trekking.com/vg/en/vluchtinfo/jaar/vbijjaar.php?id=2019'>2019</option>
<option value='http://globe-trekking.com/vg/en/vluchtinfo/jaar/vbijjaar.php?id=2018'>2018</option>
<option value='http://globe-trekking.com/vg/en/vluchtinfo/jaar/vbijjaar.php?id=2017'>2017</option>
<option value='http://globe-trekking.com/vg/en/vluchtinfo/jaar/vbijjaar.php?id=2016'>2016</option>
<option value='http://globe-trekking.com/vg/en/vluchtinfo/jaar/vbijjaar.php?id=2015'>2015</option>
<option value='http://globe-trekking.com/vg/en/vluchtinfo/jaar/vbijjaar.php?id=2014'>2014</option>
<option value='http://globe-trekking.com/vg/en/vluchtinfo/jaar/vbijjaar.php?id=2013'>2013</option>
<option value='http://globe-trekking.com/vg/en/vluchtinfo/jaar/vbijjaar.php?id=2012'>2012</option>
<option value='http://globe-trekking.com/vg/en/vluchtinfo/jaar/vbijjaar.php?id=2011'>2011</option>
<option value='http://globe-trekking.com/vg/en/vluchtinfo/jaar/vbijjaar.php?id=2010'>2010</option>
<option value='http://globe-trekking.com/vg/en/vluchtinfo/jaar/vbijjaar.php?id=2009'>2009</option>
<option value='http://globe-trekking.com/vg/en/vluchtinfo/jaar/vbijjaar.php?id=2008'>2008</option>
<option value='http://globe-trekking.com/vg/en/vluchtinfo/jaar/vbijjaar.php?id=2007'>2007</option>
<option value='http://globe-trekking.com/vg/en/vluchtinfo/jaar/vbijjaar.php?id=2006'>2006</option>
<option value='http://globe-trekking.com/vg/en/vluchtinfo/jaar/vbijjaar.php?id=2005'>2005</option>
<option value='http://globe-trekking.com/vg/en/vluchtinfo/jaar/vbijjaar.php?id=2004'>2004</option>
<option value='http://globe-trekking.com/vg/en/vluchtinfo/jaar/vbijjaar.php?id=2003'>2003</option>
<option value='http://globe-trekking.com/vg/en/vluchtinfo/jaar/vbijjaar.php?id=2002'>2002</option>
<option value='http://globe-trekking.com/vg/en/vluchtinfo/jaar/vbijjaar.php?id=2001'>2001</option>                </select>

<script>
        $(function(){
          // bind change event to select
          $('#dynamic_select').bind('change', function () {
              var url = $(this).val(); // get selected value
              if (url) { // require a URL
                  window.location = url; // redirect
              }
              return false;
          });
        });
    </script>

                </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: Can you delete this `onchange="window.location = jQuery('#urlSelect option:selected').val();"` and add `console.log(url)` to your bind function and check value in console panel also remove `return false;` it is not needed also check your '$id' it will be always the same from `$_GET` after first selection you should change it to `$j` like jeroen wrote

Answer (score 1):

In your loop you have a logical error:

```
<?php echo $id ?>
```

should be:

```
<?php echo $j; ?>
```

`$j` is the year and `$id` is fixed and the previous value in the url, so once it is wrong, it will not change.

**Edit:** Additionally, you need the value of the selected *option*, not the value of the select box.

So this:

```
var url = $(this).val();
```

Should be something like:

```
var url = $(this).find(':selected').val();
```

Comment: It would, still be the same value. This change does not affect the behavior of the script and it still redirects me to /--Select--

Comment: @DaniëlCronk What does the generated html look like? After this change of course.

Comment: I get the following page: Not Found
The requested URL /vg/en/vluchtinfo/jaar/--Select-- was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: sorry. i think the cold has gotten to my brain. I've added the generated html code to my original post.

Comment: @DaniëlCronk No problem, I have added a change in the javascript as well.

Comment: i have made the changes. still i have the same behavior

Comment: @DaniëlCronk Is the list generated like in your question, or is it added dynamically using javascript?

Comment: It is generated like in my question. The only thing javascript is supposed to be doing is using onchange to change the  load the URL with the new parameter.

Comment: @DaniëlCronk can you change javascript to this `window.location = url;` => `window.location.replace(url);`